# Removing Java Security Prompt

Tags: windows-8, security, java

I installed the software [Action(s)](http://app.jbbres.com/) on my Windows 8 machine but the annoying Java security prompt Window will not stop showing up when I launch the application:

[image]

The Java Control Panel also resets my security level back to "high" even if I launch "Configure Java" as Administrator and safe it as "medium":

[image]

These are my extended settings, disabling all verifications and checking:

[image]

Yet, the dialog keeps showing up. Which option do I need to get rid of it?

Comment: The security warning is for a reason there. Computers get often infected through java security holes, so the best would be to return all the settings to default as they were. Maybe you have more java version installed on your PC.

Comment: You don't indicate what version of Java you have installed.  Verify you have a single version installed.  If you have multiple versions that can cause setting conflicts.  Furthermore the second image is the **security setting for the java browser plugin nothing else.**

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled Java SE 8 and Java 7 then installed the newest version of both and it no longer shows the security prompt. Duh!